# RIDE setup on linux - Unable to install wxPython

Tags: linux, wxpython, robotframework

I am trying to set RIDE framework on linux.

I have installed the essential software-

> Python2.7.8
>
> pip
>
> RobotFramework 2.8.4

Facing issue while installing wxPython.

```
sudo yum install python-wxgtk2.8
```

Gave the following error:

```
Setting up Install Process
No package python-wxgtk2.8 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

same for python-wxgtk3.0

Also tried `sudo yum install wxPython`

default installed  `wxPython.x86_64 0:2.8.12.0-1.el6` package and on running ride.py getting below error-

```
You need to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 with unicode support to run RIDE.
wxPython 2.8.12.1 can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/
```

Need proper commands to execute wxPython in linux that successfully executes 
ride.py.

Comment: What distro you running?

Comment: Linux version 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@c6b8.bsys.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013.

Comment: I even tried installing wxPython 3.0.2. But  python2.7 build-wxpython.py --build_dir=../bld gives me  - "error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1ERROR: failed building wxPython."